# jboss 4.0.5.GA jax-ws issue (extremely slow)

Tags: jax-ws, jboss-4.0.x

I am having an issue with jboss 4.0.5.GA.
I'm testing a webservice (JAX-WS 2.1.3 based) and I'm having huge performance problems.

I'm facing request times like:

```
1st invocation: 20s
2nd invocation: 0.5s
3rd invocation: 9s
4th invocation: 15s
5th invocation: 10s
```

and I can see that more yhan 90% of the time is spent before reaching my code.

I don't have performance issues with other webapps in the same server that are not Jax-WS Webservices (either if the JVM is the same or another).

Is this a known issue? How can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

It's a very old version... but I think this is not the problem. Maybe it's thread local caching issue : if the WSDL (XSD) represents an important and complex class model, an instance of JAXBContext is create for each thread and it cost a lot.

You can override this to create a single static JaxbContext.

You can use VisualVM and profiling to validate this hypothesis.